# MongoDB Aggregate: Sorting by existing values first

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

My user has this field :

```
interestedIn: [{
        type: String,
        enum: [
            'art',
            'sport',
            'news',
            'calture',
            ...
        ],
    }],
```

and my video has this field:

```
categories: [{
            type: String,
            enum: [
                'art',
                'sport',
                'news',
                'calture',
                ...
            ],
        }],
```

So I need a Video query that has the following conditions:

- Query to all videos and sort by values in **req.user.interestedIn** first.
- Rest of the videos that are not match to **req.user.interestedIn** get in the last.

I got this far with said query:

```
Video.aggregate([

        { '$match': {}},
        { '$unwind': '$categories' },
        { '$match': {categories: {$in: req.user.interestedIn}}},
        { '$group': {
            '_id': '$categories',
            'categories': { '$push': '$categories' }
        }},
        { '$sort': { 'categories': 1 } }
    ])
```

This is the result:

```
   "videos": [
        {
            "_id": "art",
            "categories": [
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "news",
            "categories": [
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
   "videos": [
        {
            "_id": "art",
            "categories": [
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art",
                "art"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "news",
            "categories": [
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news",
                "news"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Something like `Video.aggregate([          { '$match': {}},         { '$unwind': '$categories' },          {"$addFields":{ "sortorder":{"$indexOfArray":[req.user.interestedIn, "$categories"]}}},   {"$sort":{"sortorder":-1}}     ])`

Comment: @Veeram tnx for answering . i get query result back but I have 100 videos in db in the result shows 367. I think query aggregate throw per element in array (InterestedIn) .

Comment: Can you show the expected response ? do you need to group the videos by category ?

Comment: I just need my videos to sort by existing of InterestedIn first

Comment: still not clear. how do we compare category with interestedIn array ? As both are array what the comparison should look like ?

Comment: suppose we have 20 videos. we have a user has interestedIn=['sport', 'art'] and I need to query to this videos by sorting the videos in this condition videos that contain interestedIn=['sport', 'art'] comes first of the query result

Comment: Something like `Video.aggregate([ { '$match': {}}, {"$addFields":{ "numofmatches":{"$size":{"$setInstersection":["$categories", req.user.interestedIn]}}}}, {"$sort":{"numofmatches":-1}} ])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181944/discussion-between-babak-abadkheir-and-veeram).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$setIntersection` to extract the matching elements followed by `$size` to count the matches.

`$sort`  descending documents on number of matches.

Something like

```
Video.aggregate([ 
  {"$addFields":{ "numofmatches":{"$size":{"$setIntersection":["$categories", req.user.interestedIn]}}}}, 
  {"$sort":{"numofmatches":-1}} 
])
```